# Multiple modules or multiple server instances for one large PHP project

Tags: php, api

I am creating a very large PHP REST API project which includes huge amount of data transportation (input and output from/to multiple databases via API calls) as well as huge amount of user interaction (user hits frontend application which in turn send API requests). For example, I would require different modules for:

1. Bulk import
2. Bulk PDFs generation
3. Bulk processing of data
4. Sending emails
5. Tracking data
6. API integration with third party tools etc.

I want to know what is an ideal way to structure or organize such big project. I found a similar post [When should we use multi-module structure (instead simple structure) in php Phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569207/when-should-we-use-multi-module-structure-instead-simple-structure-in-php-phal) . However, I need to know which is a better option:

1. Multiple folders for multiple independent small applications on just one server
2. Multiple independent small applications running on multiple server instances

Answer (score 1):

I chose option 2.

Microservices are the first post-DevOps revolution architecture. They make change less expensive and enable unique opportunities.

A proper Microservice is ‘designed for failure’.